# Read values from a txt file on an SD card

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, sd-card, arduino-makefile

I'm trying to read a text file (has numeric values) from SD card. The values in the file like this

```
87 512
255
```

I need to read 87 in ch1 and 512  in ch2 and 255 in ch3.

Why did I get on 'SKIP_NONE' 'SKIP_WHITESPACE' was not declared in this scope?

```
int ch1 = in_file.parseInt(SKIP_WHITESPACE);
Serial.printf("First = %d \n",ch1);

int ch2 = in_file.parseInt(SKIP_NONE, '\n');
Serial.printf("Second = %d \n",ch2);

int ch3 = in_file.parseInt();
Serial.printf("Third = %d \n",ch3);
```

Comment: What Arduino are you compiling for? What core version are you using?

Comment: Can I know why the -1 ??!!!

Comment: Why the -1? Because some people... (fill in the blanks).  I just corrected the transgression by upvoting your question.  Why?  Because it's a good question, and a downvote without a helpful comment serves no purpose except to discourage you, and that doesn't help anyone and only hurts the community.

Comment: Ignore the downvotes. People are allowed to downvote, and they are not required to give a reason. Just ignore them. I'm a moderator and I get downvoted. :P

Answer (score 3):

These symbols were introduced in the Arduino AVR core 1.6.7, in
December 2015. You can find them [in Stream.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.6.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Stream.h#L41-L45). They are probably
defined in other cores too.

For some reason, the Teensy cores [do not define them](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/cores/blob/master/teensy4/Stream.h). You may consider filing an issue in their GitHub project.